# Transparent material in 3D View

Tags: materials, 3d-view, transparency

I have an image of a spaceship with the front glass. I want to make a transparent material so that I can see the inner seat etc.
I do not want to change it in the render, but make the material transparent in the 3D View. 
[image: Screenshot]

How can I achieve that and what settings are required to get that transparent effect in the 3D view?

Comment: try this: set up a transparent material, switch to Material Viewport Shading, and under Material Properties > Settings >Viewport Color, bring down Alpha to 0.

Comment: @zac can u plz show me a screen shot its not working with me

Comment: @ateks you've been using this site long enough to understand that questions like this are better answered if you specify what render engine you are using, and if you post images of your current settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ateks, this is a simple example with blender render, explaining what Zac said above in comments:

[image]

simply switching to cycles (in this case) gives a similar basic material, and works the same:

[image]